# Forced Drag and Drop to select items glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I have had this problem where I have to hold down left mouse button to select items. It's like I'm dragging and dropping a file on my computer. It persists on every version of Minecraft. My OS is Windows 10.

I have tried closing the game, and reopening it, as well as removing it from my hard drive, then installing it again, but the glitch has persisted.

Comment: I have tried closing the game, and reopening it, as well as removing it from my  hard drive, then installing it again, but the glitch has persisted

Comment: Have you experienced this issue with any other programs?

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you have touchscreen mode on. You can turn it off by pressing Esc then clicking the 'Options' button. In Options, click the 'Controls' button. At the top of this menu, you should see a 'Touchscreen Mode' button. Click it, and then try to move an item in your inventory. It should now be fixed.

If you want to know why this happened, then let me explain. Touchscreen Mode has a feature where you have to drag you finger across the screen to move items. This feature was added to tell the difference between an actual person and other objects that might touch the touchscreen surface.

Hope this helped!

( This has been tested in 1.13.2 )

Answer (score 0):

You probably have configured the `pick block` feature to the left mouse button. I usually have it assigned to the R. You can change this by going in the controls options and changing the `pick block` tab under `Gameplay`:

[image]